# Populate and filter a dropdown with an array of objects using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have the following data structure thats coming from an API.

```
$scope.cityList = [{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "584ebd7f734d1d55b6dd4e5e"
},
"cityName": "New York",
"region": "north",
"people": [
    { "id": 1, "name": "x" },
    { "id": 2, "name": "y" },
    { "id": 3, "name": "z" },
    { "id": 4, "name": "a" },
    { "id": 5, "name": "b" },
    { "id": 6, "name": "c" }
]
},
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "584ebd7f734d1d55b6dd4e5e"
},
"cityName": "New Jersey",
"region": "South",
"people": [
    { "id": 1, "name": "x" },
    { "id": 2, "name": "y" },
    { "id": 3, "name": "z" },
    { "id": 4, "name": "a" },
    { "id": 5, "name": "b" },
    { "id": 6, "name": "c" }
]
}]
```

I'm trying to setup **two** dropdowns:

- the first one displays a list of the `cityNames`
- the second displays the list of all people `names` from the **selected city**.

I also want to save the `id` of the selected user name into a variable.

---

I've tried this so far:

```
<select ng-model="city">
    <option ng-repeat="city in cityList" value="{{city.cityName}}">{{city.cityName}}</option>
</select>

<select ng-model="selectedItem">
    <optgroup ng-repeat="option in cityList | filter: city">
        <option ng-repeat="x in option.people">{{x}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Where is `cityList` defined?

Comment: `cityList` is the JSON object defined at the beginning.

Comment: @lin In my angular controller, the data comes from an API and save it in the `cityList` object. i.e `$scope.cityList = dataFromAPI`

Comment: Thanks, that wasn't clear. Coding is not imaging :) You should edit your question.

Comment: You should normalize your response in JavaScript due to the use case of your dropdown's. Do you need a working example?

Comment: @lin yes a working example would be extremely helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [`ng-options`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions):

```
<select ng-model="selectedCity" 
        ng-options="c as c.cityName for c in cityList">
</select>

<select ng-model="selectedPerson" 
        ng-options="p as p.name for p in selectedCity.people">
</select>
```

[**Demo on JSFiddle.**](https://jsfiddle.net/Mistalis/boo4opz7/)

Comment: Great +1 KISS!!

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you. Learned something new today!